# Reorder Plugin Tabs in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Good day everyone,
I'm looking into Wordpress Admin Customization and I'm stuck on a point. In WP, we can easily reorder the admin tabs (Dashboard, Media, Post, etc.) with the custom_menu_order function. No problem for the native tabs and the Custom Posts, they reorders like I want them to.

The problem appears when I try to reorder plugin tabs (Like Yoast, ACF, WPML). Nothing happens.

Here's my code for now :

```
function custom_menu_order($menu_ord) {
    if (!$menu_ord) return true;

    return array(
        'index.php', // Dashboard
        'separator1', // First separator
        'upload.php', // Media
        'themes.php', // Appearance
        'link-manager.php', // Links
        'admin.php?page=wpseo_dashboard', // Yoast
        'separator', // Separator
        'plugins.php', // Plugins
        'users.php', // Users
        'tools.php', // Tools
        'options-general.php', // Settings
    );

}
add_filter('custom_menu_order', 'custom_menu_order'); // Activate custom_menu_order
add_filter('menu_order', 'custom_menu_order');
```

If you look in my array, I've put Yoast under Links, and above the separator. But in the end, he still appears at the very bottom.

Let me know if you have any idea what to do about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem was happenning only on tabs URL starting with “admin.php?page=”, I  removed it. So, to reorder Yoast, I just entered 'wpseo_dashboard' in my arrays. Result :

```
function custom_menu_order($menu_ord) {
    if (!$menu_ord) return true;

    return array(
        'index.php', // Dashboard
        'separator1', // First separator
        'upload.php', // Media
        'themes.php', // Appearance
        'link-manager.php', // Links
        'wpseo_dashboard', // Yoast
        'separator', // Separator
        'plugins.php', // Plugins
        'users.php', // Users
        'tools.php', // Tools
        'options-general.php', // Settings
    );

}
add_filter('custom_menu_order', 'custom_menu_order'); // Activate custom_menu_order
add_filter('menu_order', 'custom_menu_order');
```

It works with ACF Options Pages and any other plugin tabs.